# Disable auto-complete's pop-up menu in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

How to disable auto-complete's pop-up menu from showing up? I would simply like one simple suggestion much like in googles' suggestions (and also implemented in auto-complete itself).

Strangely it shows this in grey right before the pop up menu, how to make it stay like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following line to your init file should do the trick.

```
(setq ac-auto-show-menu nil)
```